# Fixing spotlight "code validation failed" errors?

Tags: spotlight

Every minute or so, the following ends up in syslog:

```
Oct  3 22:57:12 Mac-mini lsregister[20158] <Notice>: LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
Oct  3 22:57:12 Mac-mini lsregister[20158] <Notice>: LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
Oct  3 22:57:13 Mac-mini mdworker[20155] <Error>: code validation failed in the process of getting
signing information: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(OSStatus error -67062.)" UserInfo=0x7fa5fd803ef0 {SecCSArchitecture=i386}
```

With lots of repeats of the last line.  It's some sort of mdworker / spotlight issue, but what?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is a problem with a plist entry, first obstacle is knowing what file or app to look in...

I have been trying to fix a similar issue from mdworker scanning apps that was traced to an old style InfoPlist.strings for a Classic/OS9 emulator

Just after I succeeded in fixing that (it was quotes within quotes) I started to get

> mdworker[97078]: code validation failed in the process of getting signing information: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "(null)" UserInfo={SecCSArchitecture=ppc}

I am not sure yet as I have just expanded the detail of logs I am looking at and not confirmed the source of the new message. It should have been there as I rolled out my fix among the many copies over a few days but was not seen until I just went deeper in logs.

Hope that helps if you are still stuck! I may report back...

Comment: False assumption by me, I have traces of that error much more than fits with my change above. I have however been logging all locations accessed by my mdworker(s) and at the times I have errors it has been trawling through Spotlight plugins. I KNOW that Thunderbird spotlight plugin is flaky so I am checking if that looks like the issue (for me). YMWV.

Comment: Mmm, tough. Each time I see that error mdworker has just scanned 6500 times in hundreds of files in the enclosing 10second periods. All to do with spotlight plugins so far... also other plugins seen but that is just in some time widows. If I wanted to follow your problem I'd be looking into the spotlight plugins, try suspend spotlight, see when it started and what was installed just prior, look for any InfoPlist.strings with ""...  I'm keeping at it as I want to nail down where my errors are from!

Comment: a fingerprint of note with my issue is that there is an error for a ppc and an i386 version (SecCSArchitecture=ppc). One app only had ppc in Spotlight and it has EXACTLY JUST those 2 architectures in the Spotlight plugin: it is Transmit (the file transfer app)... So I am pointing my finger there with my problem! It is probably quite old as I have not used it for 12 months at least... Next comment I'll show how I found it, but you have i386 architecture to look for and that will be more common!

Comment: for your i386: in terminal cd /Applications    then     find . -path \*Spotlight\*MacOS\* -exec file {} \;|grep i386

Comment: on my machine for i386 there were a few more but not bad - just: MS Outlook, SKetchUP2013, Xcode, Transmit

Comment: Some apps locate or name their plugins in others ways so this is not everything but for me scanned several thousand items!